# how to use two different variables to form a new variable in TCL?

Tags: variables, tcl

I have the following code in TCL:

```
set number1 1
set number2 2
set number3 3
set array1 2
set array2 3
set array3 4
```

then how could I use variable `number1` form a the variable `array1`, for example:

```
$array$number1
```

what I want is use value of `$number1` and `$array` to form a the variable `$array1`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the syntax:

```
set number1 1
set array$number1 2
```

To get a variable `$array1` with value 2.

```
% puts $array1
2
```

And if you want to retrieve the value of a variable with variables, you can do:

```
% puts [set array$number1]
2
```

Comment: +1: Answers the question. Use Glenn's answer though.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do that, as shown by @Jerry

What you *should* do is use an array:

```
set indexes {1 2 3 4}
array set array {}
foreach idx $indexes {
    set array($idx) [expr {$idx + 1}]
}
parray array
```

```
array(1) = 2
array(2) = 3
array(3) = 4
array(4) = 5
```